# Are religions at the end more humble comparing with the more Asian streams?

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-religion

The three monotheistic religions all have a God who provides commandments and rules which are to be obeyed.

In Asian religions like Buddhism, Hinduism, and Taoism there isn't such a God who gives rules and commandments, but more of a body of wisdom and advice which one can follow and use.

So it looks that the 'ego' in western monotheism is more submissive, because at the end one has his spritual gains, but one has only done which had to be done. In the Asian traditions you also could get some spiritual gains, but it looks a bit more of your choices.

So could it be more helpfull for your spiritual wellbeing to obey and in a certain way having no choice instead of taking and choosing what is taught to be good.

Are there some philosphers who discussed this difference?

Comment: It seems like an interesting question, but the last three paragraphs are confusing and can use some editing (I fixed some of the language but not all). Can you please clarify the question?

Comment: Also the claim in the second paragraph seems like a false generalization about "Asian religions." There are many different things called "Hinduism" and many different interpretations of Buddhism. Also, there are more religions in Asia (even if we limit it to east Asia) than just these three.